# Creating wallpaper website site in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image-resizing, wallpaper

I'm trying to create a wallpapers site, using WordPress platform. The website should have similar functions like this [wallpapers](http://www.win7wallpapers.com) site. Which plugin is required to re-size images in multiple sizes, like `1920x1200`, or `1920x1080`. If there's no such plugin, how can I create this function in WordPress?

Comment: what potential solutions have you considered so far?

Comment: I've tried NextGen Gallery plugin for WordPress, but didn't get expected results. any suggestions from your side will really help.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for this:

1. Manual: Uploaded images can be edited and cropped to the required size by teh administrator.  Go to the media library, find the image, click edit and make the changes necessary
2. Automatic: I found this page by typing "how to edit image size in wordpress" when I was, in fact, looking for a manual that would explain with screenshots the instructions in step 1 above: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-additional-image-sizes-in-wordpress/

The post there makes use of the [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) function of Wordpress and tells Wordpress to automatically generate thumbnails in your required size.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Wallpaper website in WordPress is now as easy as counting 1-2-3. All you need a WordPress + decent hosting and a Wallpaper WordPress theme from https://binarynote.com

Just install Wallpaper WordPress theme along with their bulk image uploader plugin and you are ready to upload your wallpapers. The theme is able to generate different image sizes like you have mentioned automatically but will not store any such images on your server.

here is one such theme for your ready reference. https://binarynote.com/wordpress-theme-wallpaper.html

Hope this will help you a lot.